# Beautiful soup: right to left text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

RIght now I'm getting all the paragraph tags in Beautiful soup 4 for this page:

```
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align: center"><b>
                            <span lang="EN-US" style="font-family: Arial; color: blue">
                            <font size="4">1 </font></span>
                            <span lang="AR-SA" dir="RTL" style="font-family: Arial; color: blue">
                            <font size="4">&#1600;</font></span><span lang="EN-US" style="font-family: Arial; color: blue"><font size="4"> 
                            с&#1199;р&#1241; фати&#1211;&#1241;</font></span></b></p>
```

I'm trying to get the stuff in the 2 font tags, however the text comes out aligned to the right. I think that this has to do with dir="RTL"

But I want it from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
for elem in soup.findAll('font'):
    print elem.text.strip()
```

And it's because the unicode string that you get contains multiple chars that belong to the [`Separator, Space Category [Zs]`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm). You can see it yourself:

```
import unicodedata

for c in elem.text:
    print unicodedata.category(c),
```